# How do I read a text file created by an installed app from my app?

Tags: android

I've created an app which reads a text file created by an installed app. The location of this file is located at: `This PC\Galaxy S4\Phone\veryfit2.2\file.txt`.

I tried to get access to this file using `Environment` and `getBaseContext()`, but in both cases, it didn't help. How can I access the text file?

Here's the folder directory:

[image: Folder grid of folders in Windows File Explorer]

Comment: are you sure you included permissions to write and read external storage in your manifest

Comment: @LiNKeR this file is located in internal storage.

Comment: Ok. But are you sure the file is not in use by the app that created it, you might need to verify that the app isn't currently using the file via a foreground/background service whenever you're trying to access it

Comment: @LiNKeR This file is used only by eariler installed app to make i/o operations.